# Why can't u32 add or subtract i32?

Tags: rust, type-conversion, numeric, arithmetic-expressions

```
let a: u32 = 10;
let b: i32 = 100;
let c = a - b;
```

Even this simple operation doesn't work. `u32` just can't operate with `i32`. But I really wonder what's the design principle behind this. I don't think `u32 - i32` is more dangerous than `u32 - u32`. For example:

```
let a: u32 = 10;
let b: u32 = 100;
let c = a - b;
```

Does compile, but it panics at runtime. So why is Rust so paranoid about operating between different numeric types? And what's the idiomatic way to handle this, just put `as` everywhere?

I find it a bit crazy that even checked operations don't work on different numeric types.

```
let a: u32 = 10;
let b: i32 = 100;
let c = a.checked_sub(b);
```

Comment: What should the result of `u32 - i32` be? Should it be `u32` or `i32` or something else?

Comment: If you could add a signed number and an unsigned one, what should be the result? Signed number? Unsigned? There is ambiguity. And rust is all about removing implicit ambiguity in favor of being explicit. You can (and should) choose the type of the output by manually doing casts. Note that using `as` is actually considered not idiomatic, and you should use `From` and `TryFrom` traits to be sure that you won't be silently hit by an over-, or underflow.

Comment: `u32 - i32` should be `u32` to me. Ok, people might disagree on this, but `u32.checked_sub(i32)` surely should be `u32`? I really don't think it's so ambiguous.

Comment: And what if `i32` is negative and this subtraction would overflow? Should now `checked_sub` also check of overflows as well as underflows?

Comment: Yes and it's a bit hard to see why not...?

Comment: I don't know what can I add more but rust values being explicit. This is just another example of rust forcing you to think about your edge cases upfront, which can save you from nasty bugs later on.

Comment: I would add that this is much more «teachable». The rule is trivial: operations require same type without any implicit conversion. In C for example, it is a nightmare to make students understand that some conversions are implicit, some are not, and it's even worse with small integer promotion.

Comment: I really don't get why `checked_add` and `checked_sub` is not *explicit* enough for Rust. They have "checked" in the method name...? Or is there a `xxx_add` method for this use case that I missed? And while `u32.checked_add(i32)` is not explicit enough, `u32 - u32`, which panics, is okay?

Comment: The word `checked`  indicates that those functions detect overflow and return a fallible `Result` to force you to handle it, rather than panicking or silently wrapping. They don't address the ambiguity about whether the result should be `u32` or `i32`.

Answer (score 7):

This isn't unique to signed versus unsigned; Rust won't even let you add differently sized integers together:

```rust
fn main() {
   println!("{}", 5u32 + 10u16);
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:3:26
  |
3 |    println!("{}", 5u32 + 10u16);
  |                          ^^^^^ expected `u32`, found `u16`

error[E0277]: cannot add `u16` to `u32`
```

For the specific case of adding a signed value to an unsigned one, there are functions like [`checked_add_signed`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u16.html#method.checked_add_signed), [`overflowing_add_signed`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u16.html#method.overflowing_add_signed), [`saturating_add_signed`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u16.html#method.saturating_add_signed), and [`wrapping_add_signed`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u16.html#method.wrapping_add_signed).

> Ok, people might disagree on this, but u32.checked_sub(i32) surely should be u32? I really don't think it's so ambiguous.

You acknowledge in your own comment that you don't think everyone will agree on an obvious behavior, and that really is the crux of the issue. C and C++ have some awkward rules regarding integer promotion - a stray unqualified literal like `123` in an expression will convert an expression to a signed integer. Rust decided to make everything explicit.

Comment: It's not so much Rust that "won't even let you add differently sized integers" as it is just core not having implemented the relevant traits. It [could very well implement add with different rhs operators](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=3ed6104432f54fed7fd9996d8cf7c9cc)